# Tune quoted in Jinkx Monsoon's "Cartoons & Vodka"

Tags: music-video

From 2:43 to 2:47 in [Jinkx Monsoon's "Cartoons & Vodka"](https://youtu.be/ejWnwVWuoCo?t=2m40s), where is this tune from? It's so familiar, but I just can't place it.

Answer (score 5):

It refers to a part of the melody from [In the Hall of the Mountain King](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBsFYKzhk5E&t=0m59s) from Peer Gynt by Grieg.

Comment: While I agree that the brief melody in OP's reference is _influenced_ by the Grieg piece, I don't accept that this conclusively addresses OP's question. OP's ref track is clearly based on "cartoon" references, and the full riff is obviously different than the exact Grieg piece. I know that the Grieg piece was used in Looney Tunes and likely influenced the Inspector Gadget theme, but the specific run in OP's ref is also related to some other animated show that I (too) vaguely recall, but can not place.